# in Xamarin form for collection view items how to set button base on item's value? (conditional binfing)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am doing a Xamarin form project, I have a list of tasks that can be completed or in completed. I want to add a button to display "Mark as completed" for in completed tasks and "Mark as in completed" for completed tasks. of course, it needs to refresh when the user clicks once.
I have a "CompletedDate" field that defines whether the task is completed when it has value.

```
  TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryBlack}" />
                            <CollectionView  Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" x:Name="List3">
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Frame
                                        Margin="0,10"
                                        Padding="10"
                                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryWhite}"
                                        BorderColor="{StaticResource PrimaryLightGray}"
                                        CornerRadius="10"
                                        HasShadow="False">
                                                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto" RowSpacing="15">
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <Label
                                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource MeduimFont}"
                                                    Style="{StaticResource LabelMedium}"
                                                    Text="Completed"
                                                          IsVisible="{Binding CompletedTaskVisibility}}"
                                                    TextColor="{Binding PrimaryPersianGreen}" />
                                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <Image
                                                        HeightRequest="20"
                                                        Source="iconCalender.png"
                                                        WidthRequest="20" />
                                                            <Label
                                                        FontFamily="{StaticResource MeduimFont}"
                                                        Style="{StaticResource LabelMedium}"
                                                        Text="{Binding CompletedDate,StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}"
                                                        TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryBlack}" 
                                                        />
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </StackLayout>

                                                    <BoxView
                                                Grid.Row="1"
                                                HeightRequest="1"
                                                Color="{StaticResource PrimaryLightGray}" />

                                                    <Label
                                                Grid.Row="2"
                                                Style="{StaticResource LabelMedium}"
                                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryBlack}" />
                                                    <Label
                                                Grid.Row="3"
                                                Style="{StaticResource LabelMedium}"
                                                Text="{Binding Description}"
                                                TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryBlack}" />


                                                    <Button
                                                x:Name="lstbtnMarkasComplite"
                                                Grid.Row="5"
                                                Padding="15,0"
                                                Clicked="MarkTaskAsCompletedClicked"
                                                CornerRadius="20"
                                                FontSize="{StaticResource Font12}"
                                                HeightRequest="40"
                                                         CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                Style="{StaticResource ButtonPurple}"
                                                Text="Mark as Completed" />
                                                  
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Frame>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
```

I have a "CompletedDate" field that defines whether the task is completed when it has value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a [`DataTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#data-triggers) to your `Button`. They can be used to apply conditional bindings or values to properties such as the `Button.Text` property.

For a button you could implement it similarly to the following:

```
    <Button Test="Mark Complete">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsCompleted}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Mark Incomplete"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

And then you could also add the `IsCompleted` field to your viewmodel:

```cs
public bool IsCompleted             
            get { return CompletedDate.HasValue; }
```

which would act as the switch for your button.

You would also need to add notification for the `IsCompleted` variable.

Calling `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsCompleted))` when you set `CompletedDate` will do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I bind isCompleted to collectionview's item property?

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions:

1. Create a boolean variable which checks the CompletedDate in your viewmodel and binding the Text to it. And then use a converter to convert the bool to string. About the clicked event, you can try to do the same thing as the Text or do a check in the click event in the page.cs.
2. Create a boolean variable in the view model too, but you need to create two button(one is "Mark as completed" and the other is "Mark as in completed") in the xaml and binding their IsVisible property to the boolean variable in the view model.

I suggest you to try the second solution, because the first one need to do a lot and convert the clicked event to a command. And the second one reduce much work.

Finally, you may try to use some other controls instead of the button. Such as:

CheckBox:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/checkbox

Switch:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/switch

Edit:

in the view model:

```
 public ViewModel()
    {
        CompletedDate = ""; //set the value with the model data
        if (CompletedDate != null)
        {
            isCompleted = true;
        }
        else isCompleted = false;
 }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    bool isCompleted;
    public bool IsCompleted { 
        get { return isCompleted; } 
        set { 
              isCompleted = value;
              if (PropertyChanged != null)
              {
                  PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsCompleted"));
              }
            }
    }
```

in the xaml:

```
 <Button
                                            x:Name="lstbtnMarkasComplite"
                                            Grid.Row="5"
                                            Padding="15,0"
                                            Clicked="MarkTaskAsCompletedClicked"
                                            CornerRadius="20"
                                            FontSize="{StaticResource Font12}"
                                            HeightRequest="40"
                                                     CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            Style="{StaticResource ButtonPurple}"
                                            Text="Mark as Completed" 
                                            IsVisible="{Binding IsCompleted}"/>

 <Button
                                            x:Name="lstbtnMarkasComplite"
                                            Grid.Row="5"
                                            Padding="15,0"
                                            Clicked="MarkTaskAsInCompletedClicked"
                                            CornerRadius="20"
                                            FontSize="{StaticResource Font12}"
                                            HeightRequest="40"
                                                     CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            Style="{StaticResource ButtonPurple}"
                                            Text="Mark as in Completed" 
                                            IsVisible="{Binding IsCompleted}/>
```

You can also use the DataTrigger just like Ibrennan208 sayed, and then check the Text value in the page.cs:

```
     private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
     {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        if(button.Text == "Mark as Completed")
        {
            .........
        }
        else
        {
            .........
        }
     }
```

Update:

```
<Button.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding CompletedDate}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Mark Task as Completed"/>
     </DataTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I bind the Boolean to collection view items? can you give me an example?

Comment: You can check the edited answer.@Mah

Comment: You can set the value of the IsCompleted in the viewmodel's Construction method. Please check the code in the viewmodel in the answer. @Mah

Comment: so iscompleted is just one? right? I have a list of task ,how can i bind it to multiple task items completed date?

Comment: It's not only one. It is just like the `CompletedDate` filed in the viewmodel, different items have different value of the `iscompleted`. So the button in the item depend on the value of the `iscompleted` which depends on the value of the `CompletedDate` filed in each item. @Mah

Comment: in my view model i have this line:  public ObservableCollection<ProjectTaskLineItemSummary> Tasks { get; set; }  I have explained more here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72201437/how-to-bind-a-viewmodel-variable-to-observablecollection-items-in-xamarin-form?noredirect=1#comment127579372_72201437

Comment: Sorry, it's my careless, for this condition, you may need to add the bool variable `IsCompleted` into the model `ProjectTaskLineItemSummary`. Because the button is in the item of the collection view, and the item should bind the property in the model. And then you can set the `IsCompleted`  value of the `ProjectTaskLineItemSummary` in the viewmodel's Construction method or just set it when you set the value of the model. @Mah

Comment: Or you can try to bind it to the `CompletedDate` directly, please check the update in my answer.@Mah

Comment: I think this will be a great solution, you can have a try and I'm glad to receive your reply. @Mah