# how to bind a viewmodel variable to ObservableCollection items in xamarin form?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xa

I have a list of tasks that I need to bind a Boolean variable to its item.
the task object includes a completedDate property that if it has value defines the task as completed.
on the view, I need to check if it has value the button text display the text: "mark as incomplete"

----Task Object-----

```
   public class ProjectTaskLineItemSummary
{
    
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }      
    public decimal? CostMultiplier { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? CompletedDate { get; set; }
    public int? CompletedByUserId { get; set; }

    
}
```

-------viewmodel-------

```
 viewmodel()
{
 public ObservableCollection<ProjectTaskLineItemSummary> Tasks { get; set; }
...

  bool isCompleted;
        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get {
                return isCompleted;
                    }
            set
            {
                isCompleted = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
}
```

-----view----

```
 <CollectionView  Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" x:Name="List3">
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Frame
                                        Margin="0,10"
                                        Padding="10"
                                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryWhite}"
                                        BorderColor="{StaticResource PrimaryLightGray}"
                                        CornerRadius="10"
                                        HasShadow="False">
                                                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto" RowSpacing="15">
                                                  
                                                       
                                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <Image
                                                        HeightRequest="20"
                                                        Source="iconCalender.png"
                                                        WidthRequest="20" />
                                                            <Label
                                                        FontFamily="{StaticResource MeduimFont}"
                                                        Style="{StaticResource LabelMedium}"
                                                        Text="{Binding CompletedDate,StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}"
                                                        TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryBlack}" 
                                                        />
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </StackLayout>

                                                    <BoxView
                                                Grid.Row="1"
                                                HeightRequest="1"
                                                Color="{StaticResource PrimaryLightGray}" />

                                                    <Label
                                                Grid.Row="2"
                                                Style="{StaticResource LabelMedium}"
                                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryBlack}" />
                                                    


                                                    <Button
                                                x:Name="lstbtnMarkasComplite"
                                                Grid.Row="5"
                                                Padding="15,0"
                                                Clicked="MarkTaskAsCompletedClicked"
                                                CornerRadius="20"
                                                FontSize="{StaticResource Font12}"
                                                HeightRequest="40"
                                                         CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                Style="{StaticResource ButtonPurple}"
                                                Text="Mark as Completed" >
                                                        <Button.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsCompleted}" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Mark Task as In Completed"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>

                                                        </Button.Triggers>
                                                    </Button>

                                                </Grid>
                                            </Frame>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
```

I tried to assign it in view model like below but it doesn't work:

```
public override async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
        {
            await SetBusyAsync(async () =>
            {
...

                Tasks = ObjectMapper.Map<ObservableCollection<ProjectTaskLineItemSummary>>(project.TaskLineItems);

                foreach (var task in Tasks)
                {
                    isCompleted = task.CompletedDate.HasValue ? true : false;
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Model);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Notes);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Files);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Tasks);

            });
        }
```

Comment: you are setting the private `isCompleted` field, not the public `IsCompleted` property

Comment: also, there is only one `IsCompleted` property for multiple `Task` objects on your VM.  Shouldn't each `Task` have it's own `IsCompleted` property?

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: You didn’t answer the question I asked.  To me your VM doesn’t make any sense, but there may be a reason for doing it that way that you haven’t explained.

Comment: oh sorry. Task object has "CompletedDate" field, which defines the button text. if it has value my button should be "mark as incompleted" otherwise should be "Mark as completed". so if I want to use triggers how can I handle it? because I have multiple task on xaml with same field as "CompletedDate".   I mean do I need multiple iscompleted as well? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could simply be achieved by `Binding` `Text` Property of the button and then dynamically set the `Text` of the button based on the `CompletedDate` of the entity.
Below is the code snippets for your reference:

**Model:**
ProjectTaskLineItemSummary.cs

```
public class ProjectTaskLineItemSummary
    {
        public int TenantId { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal? CostMultiplier { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? CompletedDate { get; set; }
        public int? CompletedByUserId { get; set; }
        public string CompletedButton { get; set; } 
    }
```

**View:**

```
 <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" x:Name="List3" Background="aqua">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Frame Margin="0,10" Padding="10"  HasShadow="False">
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto" RowSpacing="15">
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image HeightRequest="30" Source="XamarinLogo.png" WidthRequest="80" />
                                <Label x:Name="mydate" Text="{Binding CompletedDate,StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}" TextColor="Black"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="1" Color="Black" />

                            <Label Grid.Row="2"  Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" />

                            <Button Grid.Row="5" x:Name="lstbtnMarkasComplite" Padding="15,0" 
                                                Clicked="MarkTaskAsCompletedClicked"
                                                CornerRadius="20"
                                                Text="{Binding CompletedButton}"
                                                FontSize="Medium"
                                                HeightRequest="40"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            </Button>

                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
 public class PageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ObservableCollection<ProjectTaskLineItemSummary> Tasks { get; set; }
        bool isCompleted { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get => isCompleted;
            set
            {
                isCompleted = value;

                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                   new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsCompleted)));
            }
        }
        string completed { get; set; }
        public String CompletedButton
        {
            get => completed;
            set
            {
                completed = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                 new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CompletedButton)));
            }
        }
        public PageViewModel()
        {
           
            Tasks = new ObservableCollection<ProjectTaskLineItemSummary>()
            {

                new ProjectTaskLineItemSummary(){TenantId = 1, Id =1, Name = "jobs ", Description= "jjjj",CostMultiplier=1 ,CompletedDate =DateTime.UtcNow, CompletedByUserId=1 ,CompletedButton = ""},
                new ProjectTaskLineItemSummary(){TenantId = 2, Id =2, Name = "james ",Description= "aaaa",CostMultiplier=2 , CompletedByUserId=2,CompletedButton = "" },
                new ProjectTaskLineItemSummary(){TenantId = 3, Id =3, Name = "rollex ",Description= "rrrr",CostMultiplier=3 ,CompletedDate =DateTime.UtcNow, CompletedByUserId=3 ,CompletedButton = ""}
            };
            setButtonIsCompleted();
        }

        private void setButtonIsCompleted()
        {
           foreach (var task in Tasks)
            {
                if (task.CompletedDate == null)
                {
                     task.CompletedButton = "Mark Task as Completed";
                }
                else
                {
                    task.CompletedButton = "Mark Task as inCompleted";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```